# Unable to start X11 through ssh using Putty

Tags: ssh, x11, putty, mininet

Currently trying to setup the mininet virtual machine. I did all according to the instructions. Before proceeding following is my setup details.

- My host platform - Windows 8.1
- My guest OS : Ubuntu 14.04, 32-bit    with mininet. I downloaded the
  ovf this one -    mininet-2.2.0-141209-ubuntu-14.04-server-i386. Running on VirtualBox
- I installed the required packages on the mininet-ubuntu-server (xserver-xorg-core,xserver-xorg,xorg,xorg openbox,ubuntu-desktop). One package fxlrg, I could not install as it was saying "unable to locate package"
- Then I used the command "startx" on virtualbox console, it started the ubuntu desktop but very slow and with poping up 4 to 5 errors.
- I have already setup the network for host-only adapter, I am able to ping from host machine to guest machine, I am able to ssh from host machine to guest machine using PuTTy. I am able to login with no problems.

But I don't know to see the x11 window from PuTTy. I have already enabled the X11 forwarding on PuTTy and I have already installed the Xming on windows. Please suggest how to debug and how to fix this. I have no idea how to proceed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to enable X11 SSH Forwarding in the /etc/ssh/ssh_config file.